# As (It) Relates To

Tags: meaning, usage, legalese, as

What do "as relates to" and "as it relates to" mean in here:

> [link](http://www.cliffsnotes.com/cliffsnotes/literature/define-mood-as-it-relates-to-a-work-of-fiction--distinguish-mood-from-effect)
> Define mood as it relates to a work of fiction
>
> [link](http://www.michigan.gov/lara/0,4601,7-154-35299_61343_35414_60647_46937-210893--,00.html)
> Sales Tax as Relates to Auctions

Are "as it relates to" and "as relates to" different?

Comment: The second sentence is a headline. Headlines tend to be abbreviated, by omitting articles usually. Probably omitting pronouns like *it* is OK too.

Comment: @CopperKettle So, what does "as it relates to" mean?

Comment: @meatie If we replace "as it relates to" with "the way it relates to", will it make sense for you?

Comment: @DamkerngT. Substituting in "the way it relates to", I have  "Define mood the way it relates to a work of fiction", which is still not clear.

Comment: @meatie Does this sentence make sense? "He walks the way a general would walk."

Comment: @DamkerngT. So, the way of defining mood should be the same as the way mood is related to fiction?

Comment: Yes. In other words, the first sentence roughly means "Define mood". But (define it) in what way? "In the way that it (the mood) relates to a work of fiction." You might also want to check this out: http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/as?q=as#as, sense 2.

Comment: @DamkerngT. But how can the act of defining mood be similar to the act of mood being related to fiction?  "He walks as a general walks" makes sense, because the same acts (walking) are being compared.  But "defining" and "relating" are two different acts.

Comment: You might want to read this part again: "What do you want us to do?" "Define mood". "In what way?" "In the way that it (the mood) relates to a work of fiction."

Comment: @DamkerngT. How should I read [this](http://maylorber.com/insights/indianas-troubling-firearm-laws-as-they-relate-to-public-schools/):  "Indiana's troubling firearm laws ***as they relate to*** public schools "

Comment: The best way to read it is to read it as "as they relate to". This might sound weird, but the best way to read is to read things as they are. Rephrasing can be helpful. Definitions given by dictionaries can also be helpful. But unless you develop the sense to understand words and phrases the way they are, you will soon run into a similar problem again. *"Indiana's troubling firearm laws as they relate to public schools"* means [Indiana's troubling firearm laws] [as [they relate to public schools]]. I used "in the way" to help you to understand it, not to have you taking it as the only meaning.

Comment: @DamkerngT.  So,  "Indiana's troubling firearm laws as they relate to public schools " should be read in the same spirit as "my situation as time goes by"?

Comment: No. Why? Because *as* has many different senses. (This is common for most easy-looking words. *Get*, *be*, *do*, *make*, are also easy-looking words, but they all have a very wide range of usages, and so does *as*.) Basically (but not exhaustively), *as* can suggest a comparison (*as ... as*), can mean *like*, can be used in *as if*, be used to indicate things that happen at about the same time ("as time goes by" likely falls into this category; likely, because a strange context could make us reinterpret its meaning), be used to mean *because* or *since*, or be used as *(even) though*.

Comment: @DamkerngT.  So, what exactly does "as" mean in my original sentence?

Comment: I think thinking of those *as* as "the way" (or *in the way that*, or *according to the way that*, or *according to the way it*) should work. Just pick any that you think works for you. According to this dictionary, http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/as?q=as#as, I think 2.1 is close enough.

Comment: @DamkerngT. Would "Define mood ***with the way*** it relates to a work of fiction" and "Indiana's troubling firearm laws ***with the way*** they relate to public schools" be good substitute for the two example sentences?

Comment: Using *with* makes me think of what follows as the reason/cause, which is opposite to *as*, which makes me think of what follows as the result/consequence.

Comment: @DamkerngT. Would "Define mood ***given the way*** it relates to a work of fiction" and "Indiana's troubling firearm laws ***given the way*** they relate to public schools" be (finally?) good substitutes for the two example sentences?

Comment: I think I couldn't make sense of this rephrasing (using *given the way*).

Comment: @DamkerngT.  Would "Define mood ***that*** relates to a work of fiction" and "Indiana's troubling firearm laws ***that*** relate to public schools" work?

Comment: I'd like to suggest avoid trying to replace it as such. Replacing *as* with *that* might make sense, but it'd change the meaning of the phrase.

Comment: @DamkerngT.  I am so frustrated!  Okay, would "Define mood ***related*** to a work of fiction" and "Indiana's troubling firearm laws ***related*** to public schools" work?

Comment: All your attempts are close (though some might be ungrammatical, in my opinion) but not quite. (I still think that "the way" or "in the way that" works better.) Perhaps, you can start with some sentences or phrases that contain an *as*-clause and you can understand its meaning clearly. How about "the world as we know it" or "I bought my new desktop computer as is from the store"?

Comment: @DamkerngT. "the world as we know it" or "the world as it existed back then" are different from "the laws as they relate to....".

Comment: How do you mean? (You could also try to explain the difference between "the world as we know it" and "the X as they relate to" to gain the insight of its usage.)

Comment: @DamkerngT. Actually, I don't quite know how to analyze "the world as we know it".

Comment: It's difficult for me to explain. (I could write its meaning, I could give you its definition as defined by dictionaries, but I'm not sure if it could help you to understand it.) I'd still like to recommend you to "start with some sentences or phrases that contain an *as*-clause and you can understand its meaning clearly", as I said before. Find a similar sentence that uses *as* in this sense that you know its exact meaning in your first language. (I'm thinking about movie subtitles and translated books. Pick one that its translation was carefully done. Don't use Google Translate.)

Comment: @DamkerngT. Would "Define mood ***to the extent*** it relates to a work of fiction" and "Indiana's troubling firearm laws ***to the extent*** they relate to public schools" really finally work?

Comment: I would say it's close but not quite. I wouldn't rephrase them that way myself, though I can imagine other people might.

Comment: @DamkerngT. Would the combo "***in the way and to the extent*** they relate to" be the right answer after all the effort?

Comment: I would say it could be considered as you said. However, I'd like to avoid that because I'm so afraid that confirming such as idea could encourage you to go further down this gloomy path. In my opinion, paraphrasing could be a good idea if it makes the learner understand the given text better. However, it would be a bad idea to think that we should always be able to substitute one phrase with another in all occasions. For example, we could think of *as* as this clumsy phrase "in the way and/or to the extent and/or at the moment and/or for the reason" but it's a really bad idea to do so.

Comment: @DamkerngT.  For some reason, "laws ***as they currently exist***" and "laws ***as they relate to*** [something]" are very different to me, with the former making complete sense but the latter making very little sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let’s take a simpler example: a cookie.

> - Joe, define cookie *as it relates to* Internet browsing.
> - Well, a [cookie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie) is a snippet of data that a website uses to identify visitors.
> - Joe, define cookie *as it relates* to cuisine.
> - Well, a [cookie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cookie) is a snippet of baked dough that a person uses to satiate himself.

That is, we have a notion (cookie, mood, sales tax, firerarm laws) that may have different meanings or shades of meaning in different segments of life.

In the case with

> Indiana's troubling firearm laws *as they relate* to public schools

-- Jeffery Johnson, the author of [the blog post](http://maylorber.com/insights/indianas-troubling-firearm-laws-as-they-relate-to-public-schools/), abstains from looking at this set of laws in general. He instead takes an example of a typical public school, narrowing down the discussion. He imagines strange scenarios that might arise in a typical public school environment due to these laws' peculiarities. There's another expression that could be used here:

> Indiana's troubling firearm laws *as they apply* to public schools

Comment: So, "Indiana's troubling firearm laws ***as they relate to*** public schools" should be read as "Indiana's troubling firearm laws ***WHEN they relate to*** public schools"

Comment: I understand your meaning of "when" here (= "in cases when they are used in public school environments"), but I'm not sure if this construction would look natural. I find myself expecting some continuation to this sentence, and so might a native speaker.

Comment: "In the context of" - Indiana's firearm laws may be troubling for any number of reasons, but the author is asking for a restricted context: public schools.